# Powershell import-csv not recognized

Tags: powershell, csv, batch-file, import-csv

I'm trying to make a bat file script that appends the information of a csv to another already existing csv file. I want to use the import-csv command, but I keep getting the error that says:

> 'import-csv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I was using Powershell 5.1, so I tried downloading and using Powershell Core 6. That isn't working either. Am I missing a library somewhere?

my code:

```
import-csv "tinyTesterB.csv"

pause
```

Comment: You're trying to run a built-in `powershell.exe` cmdlet inside `cmd.exe`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside of a bat file or in the cmd shell, you need to start PowerShell to gain access to its commands. Add the following to your bat file instead:

**For Windows PowerShell:**

```
Powershell.exe -Command "Import-Csv 'tinyTesterB.csv'"
```

**For PowerShell Core:**

```
Pwsh.exe -Command "Import-Csv 'tinyTesterB.csv'"
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining why this is the case. Do I need to add this prefix to every line? is there a way to make it so that I don't have to add it to every line?

Comment: I would create a .ps1 file with the Powershell commands. Then I would call the file `Powershell.exe -File 'c:\file.ps1'`